# get an attachment's media tags or check if it has a media tag?

Tags: tags, media

Is there a way i can get media_tags assigned to an attachment (by id)? And/or check if an attachment has a media_tag?

Not sure if i'm missing something but there seems to be very little support for doing this?

any help appreciated, Dc

Answer (score 1):

Use the [plugin Media Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/). It has lot of useful features, including bulk administration and roles management. It is translatable or translated too.